# GitHub Desktop isn't launching, only a white window

Tags: github, windows-10, github-desktop

I've been using GitHub desktop for around 3-4 months now. I never had an issue with the application before. Today, when I tried to launch the program, only a white window appeared and I can't reach the program. My operating system is Windows 10. I checked all the Windows updates and restarted my computer. I removed the GitHub Desktop twice and re-installed it. The last time, I also cleaned the AppData/Local and AppData/Roaming GitHub Desktop files before re-installing the application. I tried ctrl+shift+I, running the program through Git Bash, but still nothing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @JJAsghar,
Thank you for your suggestion. Since I've resolved the problem and I fear if I try to get the code by re-installing the version that probably caused the problem, I might have to deal with the same trouble all over. To prevent other people from struggling with this as I did, I left the solution that worked for me in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all files regarding the program and then re-installing version 2.9.5 did the trick for me. Still going to keep the post and this answer if anyone runs into the same issue.